# Nested params with cURL?

Tags: curl, parameters

I've got an iPhone app requesting an API, and it uses a nested param structure to pass in a username and password to login.

In my Rails controller, I'm successfully retrieving this information normally using:

```
username = param[:session][:username]
```

I'd like to test my API from shell, using cURL.  But I can't figure out how to provide nested params? The code below does NOT work... And I've tried multiple variations. But just can't seem to figure it out?

```
curl -d '{"session":{"username":"test","password":"password"}}' http://testurl/remote/v1/sessions
```

Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Different frameworks may interpret http query params differently, but for rails you should be able to get away with the following:

```
curl -d 'session[username]=name&session[password]=pwd' http://testurl/remote/v1/sessions
```

Comment: 10 years later, but this causes a unexpected token parse error

Comment: This caused a token parse error in a Rails 7 app for me. You should try to use `-d` or `--data` like so: `curl --data '{"name":"bob"}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://example.com/users/1234`

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work. Given a JSON blob like

```
{ "opts": {
    "finder": { 
      "cname":"superlatives"
    }
  }
}



curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -X POST \
  --data-binary '{"opts":{"finder":{"cname":"superlatives"}}}' \
  http://YOURSERVER.com/api/grams/one
```

Comment: note that just `--data` strips CR and LF so you could use that too if you want to pretty print your JSON