# Posting nested params with curl -F flag

Tags: php, django, api, rest, curl

I’m trying to post an image and a few nested parameters to an api using django rest framework. I’m trying to set up a curl with -F flags [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398696/upload-image-to-imagefield-with-djangorestframework-using-json-and-test-this-wit) with nested params as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860654/nested-params-with-curl):

```
curl -X POST -S -H 'Accept: application/json' -F "customer[name]=foo&customer[email]=foo@bar.com&customer[zipcode]=1076AL&customer[city]=Amsterdam&customer[address]=foobar" -F "photo=@/Users/vincentvanleeuwen/Desktop/tmp/accord.jpg;type=image/jpg" http://localhost:8000/api/orders/
```

But I get the following response:

```
{"customer":{"city":["This field is required."],"email":["This field is required."],"zipcode":["This field is required."],"name":["This field is required."]}}
```

There seems to be something wrong with my nesting under the -F flag, as the nested variables work if I post it like this:

```
curl -X POST -S -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"customer":{"name":"Adriaan","email":"adriaan@adriaan.com","zipcode":"1901ZP","address":"caravan","city":"Verweggistan"}}' http://localhost:8000/api/orders/
```

Any ideas what I’m doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try separate -F flags for each parameter? From the curl manual:

> Emulate a fill-in form with -F. Let's say you fill in three fields
>   in a   form. One field is a file name which to post, one field is your
>   name and one   field is a file description. We want to post the file
>   we have written named   "cooltext.txt". To let curl do the posting of
>   this data instead of your   favourite browser, you have to read the
>   HTML source of the form page and   find the names of the input fields.
>   In our example, the input field names   are 'file', 'yourname' and
>   'filedescription'.
>
> ```
>     curl -F "file=@cooltext.txt" -F "yourname=Daniel" \
>          -F "filedescription=Cool text file with cool text inside" \
>          http://www.post.com/postit.cgi
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now by using the separate -F flags, but had to change my models to avoid nesting parameters. Without the nesting it now works...